# Delphi XE IDE code parser error: "Expected '>' but '.' found."

Tags: delphi, parsing, ide, delphi-xe

After adding a `IdUDPServer` to my form and trying to put some code into the `OnUDPRead` event, I'm not able to add any component to my form at design time, nor can I run the application.

[image: this is the error i'm getting]

**is there any way to solve this ?**

Answer (score 1):

There are two bugs with this event handler. To fix them, you can

- remove the System. from `TArray<System.Byte>` (in the interface and implementation)
- add `IdSocketHandle`to the uses list in the interface

I have not investigated further but after these changes the code can be compiled.

So the full code would like be

```
unit Unit12;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, 
  IdSocketHandle, // <-- added
  IdBaseComponent, IdComponent, IdUDPBase, IdUDPClient, IdUDPServer;

type
  TForm12 = class(TForm)
    IdUDPClient1: TIdUDPClient;
    IdUDPServer1: TIdUDPServer;
    procedure IdUDPServer1UDPRead(AThread: TIdUDPListenerThread;
      AData: TArray<Byte>; ABinding: TIdSocketHandle);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form12: TForm12;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm12.IdUDPServer1UDPRead(AThread: TIdUDPListenerThread;
  AData: TArray<Byte>; ABinding: TIdSocketHandle);
begin
  //
end;
```

Comment: The above code compiles, but it doesn not work. I`ve made a simple app which uses 2 `IdUDPServer` comps, one to broadcast and one to Listen, works as expected in Delphi 2010 but if brought in DelphiXE and builded does not work, not even if i replace `TArray<Byte>` with `TBytes` as in D2010

Comment: Maybe an update to a newer release of Indy 10 helps, the 'unofficial' daily snapshots are available at ftp://ftp.fulgan.com/ZIP (current: Indy10_4454.zip)

Comment: i have tried `Indy10_4454.zip` and `Indy10Tiburon_4448.zip` with no luck, same behavior.

Comment: I have just checked in an update that makes the IDE auto-add the missing IdSocketHandle unit reference.  But the TArray issue is a bug in the IDE and Embarcadero will have to address that one in a future Update Pack.